# native app using url in cordova/phonegap HTML5 performance

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, phonegap-build

So we're developing using NodeJS, angular, html5 and all that jazz. But we want to have a more native app experience. So we're going to use ionic. However, instead of building the app as a local app and pulling in the data we want, they've decided to just build a web app and point the native app to the wep apps url.

So it's a glorified browser that looks like a native app.

Do we lose the ability to harness the devices hardware? Such as hardware acceleration and access to the devices tools like the camera. If you could provide a link to an article detailing the cons of this approach, that would be fantastic.

Comment: If you are just pointing to an external url, don't do that, just let the users access from the browser they want, browsers usually run faster than webviews

Answer (score 0):

@Chauncey, If you are using phonegap, you are a liberty to use any of the hardware devices you have permission to use, as long as you have the plugins loaded.

However, both Google Play and Apple iTunes frown on having Apps that are just *glorified browser*. There is another misconception. Phonegap Apps can have as much look and feel as native Apps. With Ionic and others, those things are done for you, and hidden from you. So with Ionic, your native look and feel is only as good as Ionic gives you.

Oh, and your request for for links to articles [lgtfy](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple%20frowns%20on%20website%20wrappers) --Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Pointing on an external URL is not a good idea.
A mobile app should have all images/css/scripts on device in order to shrink network access.
That you want to do will be really slow and does not offer a good user experience. In this way, your application can be rejected by Apple when you will submit it to AppStore.

Cordova/Phonegap needs to run some scripts at start and then raises events. You can't use device specific hardware before that. And if you redirect the main frame to an URL, you will overwrite these scripts ...